# Another "how to run code X times" inside Arduino loop()

Tags: arduino

Okay take it differently.
We know the Arduino loop() function loops everything inside consecutively.
Imagine a simple p1() trigged function that does something. Is there at least a way to repeat it X times (the hold variable here) .. and how? This gives nothing:`if (ledPattern == '1') {do{p1();} while (hold > 1);}` or `if(ledPattern == '1'){for (int i = hold; i > 0 ; i--){p1();}}`but I can imagine the problem is elsewhere in my code ...

Comment: add the code section where you assign a value to mqttmessage!
where is the rest of your loop function? It's a nice idea to keep your code as short as possible. Unfortunately you've overdone it and removed lines relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `loop` function in Arduino is meant to loop indefinitely, but I guess it is what you want as you may want to check your messages not only once.

If you want the code to stop at the end of all your `if` statements, you can add a `while(1);` at the end of your code?

How are you reading your messages? This part of the code might be important.

(Not sure this deserve an answer, but I can not comment…)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Arduino Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Loop?setlang=it):

> the loop() function does precisely what its name suggests, and loops
>   consecutively

If you want to stop the loop permanenly you can add a `while(1);` to its end. That way your Arduino will call `loop()` once and then be trapped in an infinite loop until you reset it. But of course your Arduino won't do anything else then.

If you don't want to end up in the same if block over and over you have to make sure that `mqttmessage`'s value changes after one run of `loop()`.

Otherwise, let's say `mqttmessage` equals `'1'` you'll enter the first if statement and call `p1()` hold times. Then when loop is run again and `mqttmessage` has still the same value, you again end up in the first if statement and call `p1()` hold times and so forth.

If you cannot update `mqttmessage`'s value every loop and if you don't won't to freeze your Arduino in an infinite loop, you can use a variable that stores if you have entered that if statement befor and each if statement needs to check that variable so you don't enter again.